# Volume rotated about the $y$-axis using disc/washer method

Tags: calculus

I have an area bounded by $y=\sqrt{x}$, $y=0$, and $x=9$.

I want to revolve this about the $y$ axis using the washer method.

I've sketched my region.  It should look as it looks below.

[image]

Now, I know I need to take $\pi$ $\int R^2-r^2$.   When we have $x$ equaling a constant, I don't know how to find $R$.  I know my $r$ is $y^2$.  I tried to make $R=9$, but I come out with a negative number.  Possibly my limits of integration are wrong. Am I integrating from $0$ to $3$ or $0$ to $9$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. The volume is given by
$$\pi\int_{y=0}^3  (9^2-(x(y))^2) dy$$
What is $x(y)$ here?

Comment: x(y) is y^2.  However, it is not this simple is it?  We are using the disc method which means it is going to make a doughnut so we need to "take out the middle."

Comment: No, it is bounded by x=9, y=sqrt(x), and y=0.  So, the discs are not stacked along the y-axis.  They are stacked between sqrt(x) and x=9.

Comment: @Tye Campbell I made a correction because I misunderstood the area that was revolving.

Comment: Ah, OK.  So my limits of integration were wrong.  I had my limits of integration going from 0 to 9.  So, 972pi/5?

Comment: Yes. I got the same result.